# Send MessageAttachment on another thread

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

I'm currently writing a discord bot for my discord server and someone spotted that the bot hangs when a MessageAttachment is sent, one of my developers told me to use Worker Threads from Node.JS, I tried and I couldn't get it working. What do I do?

My Worker Class

```
import { DMChannel, MessageAttachment, TextChannel } from 'discord.js';
import process from 'process';

export class AttachmentUploader {

    private _process = process;

    public constructor(attachment: MessageAttachment, channel: TextChannel | DMChannel) {
    
        this._process.on('message', () => {
            channel.send(attachment);
        });
    }

}
```

The class that uses that class

```
        message.channel.send(`${Emojis.ANIMATED_LOADING} Creating the Canvas from the CanvasBuilder class!`)
            .then(async(message) => {
                const built_canvas = await canvas.build();
                const worker = new AttachmentUploader(built_canvas, message.channel as TextChannel);

                message.edit(`${Emojis.ANIMATED_CHECKMARK} Finished creating the Canvas from the CanvasBuilder class!`);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    message.delete();
                }, 2500);
            });
```